# Visual Studio 2012 Displays Wrong Icon For Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a sample solution that has a different "test" icon on one of the test projects, but not on the other two.

[image: Test Icon]

I thought that maybe the project type guid was different on this project, but in the solution file they all have the same project type (C#)

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DomainModel.Tests", "DomainModel.Tests\DomainModel.Tests.csproj", "{61A4733D-4C5B-4705-98CB-8048751BBEFA}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Extensions.Tests", "Extensions.Tests\Extensions.Tests.csproj", "{1D6AA1C5-1FEC-44E4-9258-ACF84A20353C}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Repository.Tests", "Repository.Tests\Repository.Tests.csproj", "{248434B7-3690-4705-85F0-66B765AEB431}"
EndProject
```

And in each project file they have idential project types (Test and C#)

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Why does DomainModel.Tests have the correct test icon, but Extensions.Tests and Repository.Tests have a plain C# library icon?

Comment: Report this at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Done: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764003/visual-studio-2012-displays-wrong-icon-for-test-project

Comment: I would look into the csproj for the one correct and one not correct. I would then find the "ProjectGuid" for each and then do a search inside the .sln file to find where they are wired and look for differences. Hope this makes sense. I have the same issue, but unfortunately I dont have even one showing correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can also happen in VS2013 when starting with a class library project and then adding test classes from there.

Adding the following child node to the main PropertyGroup node in the project file fixes the icon in this case:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: This is just what I did. Your fix was spot on. Thank you!

Comment: Great thanks! I used that trick to force test icon for class library with [xUnit](https://xunit.github.io/) tests.

Comment: You also need to add `<TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>`

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in the Visual Studio 2013 preview.

Answer (score 2):

This problem isn't fixed in VS2012 Update 2 (VS2012.2).

I would expect that it will be fixed in the next version of Visual Studio if it isn't fixed in a quarterly update before then. With all of Microsoft moving to shorter release cycles (approximately 12 monthly) then we shouldn't have that long to wait; at least not compared to how long we've had to wait in the past! :-)