# What does a erlenmeyer flask icon over project in visual studio mean?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, icons

I've searched high and low, but cannot find out what this icon indicates. It appears over one of my project icons in visual studio (2012). See image below:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some software package UI, not about programming.

Comment: It is the "I'm a unit test project" icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a SourceGear Vault icon. Vault only shows icons for source control status, like checked out, old, renegade, etc.

It might be a beaker, and an icon in Visual Studio.  See this from Microsoft:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774775/test-project-icon-toggles-when-expanding-collapsing

Comment: That's it. You are right. Nothing to do with sourcegear. I've edited my question. Thank you very much for posting. Here is another SO question which addresses the icon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528335/visual-studio-2012-displays-wrong-icon-for-test-project

Comment: This is how it gets created https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/create-a-unit-test-project?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 5):

It says that the particular project is a Test case project.